# Office fabric react + typescript

Tags: office-fabric

Do we really need to know typescript for developing office fabric ui app using react library?
The samples provided for office fabric react in official website deals with typescript always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should be able to use JavaScript as well. It is a normal npm package.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Also, I would like to know if we need to take the advantage of styling office fabric components (and with react library), any documentation available. The documentation given by Microsoft deals with typescript only. For example, take the Combobox example mentioned in this link - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/ComboBox

Comment: I’m not sure I understand you, but in general whenever you can use TypeScript, you can use JavaScript as well. Just ignore the types.